# PHP - apply strtolower to form field

Tags: php, forms, lowercase

I am absolutely sure this will have been covered but have searched and cannot see how to apply strtolower in this form. Maybe I'm looking at the wrong solution. I have a form:

```
<form id="demo-b" method="get" action="<?php echo home_url( '/' ); ?>">
<div class="input-prepend">
<input class="skip-search" type="search" placeholder="Search" id="prependedInput" name="s" value="<?php the_search_query(); ?>">
<input type="hidden" name="sentence" value="1">
</div>
</form>
```

I am trying to convert the search input to lower case and from what I've seen PHP strtolower may be the solution but I'm not sure how to correctly insert it. Can anyone assist? Perhaps I've got the wrong solution?

Additional Info...

I am trying to sanitize search input to convert user input to the term used on my site. There are just a couple of terms and the following code is used (this is Wordpress and apologies if I've posted in the wrong place but I thought it was a specific PHP issue)...

```
/*sanitise search queries manually*/
$search_replacements = array(
'tilt shift' => 'tilt-shift',
'depth of focus' => 'depth of field'
);
function modify_search_term($request_vars) {
global $search_replacements;
if (!empty($request_vars['s']) && !empty($search_replacements[$request_vars['s']])) {
    $request_vars['s'] = $search_replacements[$request_vars['s']];
}
return $request_vars;
}
add_filter('request', 'modify_search_term');
```

The problem is that search terms are not case sensitive but as soon as I add them to this array they become case sensitive. I could add multiple versions of the term but it seemed sensible to convert the search term to lower case so that it returns the correct results. Perhaps this is the code that needs editing to correctly edit the form input on the server side? The client can use capitals as much as they like as far as I am concerned.

Comment: As in, you only want lower case characters entered? Or you want to insert a lowercase string yourself before the user types?

Comment: Do you mean convert it to lower case in the script that processes the form?

Comment: you mean strtolower($_GET['s']) ?

Comment: de-couple your UI from the strlower stuff and use javascript to lowercase that string as part of validations for showing and submitting.  Then on your serverside (in whatever class takes that search term) lower it, before searching and before passing it back to the UI.

Comment: Why not use javascript? Unless you're doing the convert on the server side, there's no need to do it in php.

Comment: @EmmyS validations!  if someone disables javascript in their browser they can bypass your validations and insert potentially unsafe search strings (granted they're leaving the validations client side).  This is just a tolower() example, but even so, always a good to validate at both ends of the spectrum.

Comment: Thank you all for such rapid comments. I'll add additional detail to my original question with more code. I may be looking in the wrong place.

Comment: @MikeMcMahon, yes, I'm aware that you should validate on the server-side, but the OP didn't mention anything about that. He specifically said he wanted to do it "in the form", not that he needed to convert the form's posted data.

Comment: My apologies, I may well have moved the goal posts. My apologies. I think server side solution would be best as seems to me to be a server side issue?

Comment: Haha I thought my question might get down-voted but I'll take it on the chin. I wish I didn't have to ask in the first place but if code is poetry then it's poetry in a language I can read better than write  :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to use Javascript for this because PHP is processed after you submit the form or if you use AJAX then that's a different and inefficient story.

**Javascript**

```
<input type="text" value="" onKeyPress="this.value = this.value.toLowerCase();" onKeyUp="this.value = this.value.toLowerCase();" onKeyDown="this.value = this.value.toLowerCase();">
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2esax/)

**Server-side PHP**

```
$_POST['s'] = strtolower($_POST['s']);

// Do whatever you want with the search term now because it is lower-case
```

Comment: Thank you all very much. This answer covers both sides. I'm not sure where to add / adapt the server side code in my code to be honest so if anyone can assist that would be great. The Javascript gets the lower case text across to the server anyway and I've tested mobile and various browsers down to IE8. Server side re-enforcement would be great in case of issue on client side. Accepted with much thanks.